# command to get username via id

Tags: passwd, getent

There is a command `id` to get the user id. E.g. `id -u root`gives me `0`. Is there an opposite command to get the user name via the id?
I know I can `grep` `/etc/passwd`or run `getent` and `awk` or `cut`the result. My question is if there is a dedicated command or utility I don't know?

Update:

Note that the accepted answer `id -un UID` requires recent coreutils.
E.g. on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS you get:

```
> id -un 0
id: 0: no such user
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id` works for me:

```
$ id -un 0
root
```

From [`man id`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/id.1.html):

```
-n, --name
      print a name instead of a number, for -ugG
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and if I enter  `id -un 0` I get `id: 0: no such user`

Comment: @Veterinarian Consider upgrading `coreutils`, then.

Comment: I've tried it on debian jessie and Mac and it works. So either an ubuntu bug or a bug/missing feature in the older version. What a pitty ... so it cannot be used reliably in scripts. I'll accept your answer anyways.

Comment: @Veterinarian It was added in coreutils 8.22. 14.04 has 8.21.